# Privacy Pane wont let me add a preference pane to control my computer

Tags: preferences, privacy, third-party

I have a 2010 Macbook Pro 15 inch and i just upgraded to yosemite with a fresh install (no data on any hard drives). I am trying to set up FunctionFlipper, a third party preference pane that will let me turn my dashboard key into another key (i ant to use it to show launchpad).

I installed it even though its from an unidentified developer by opening it manually with command click and open. But to use it i need to add FunctionFlip.prefpane to my list of apps that can control my computer under the privacy tab. When i unlock it to be edited and hit the plus button, i navigate to Libraries -> Preference Pane but the functionflip.prefpane is grayed out and it wont let me add it to the list.

How do i add Function Flipper to the list of apps that are allowed to control my computer?

[image: screenshot of greyed out pref pane]

Comment: Allow access to FunctionFlipper app to control your computer in sys pref Security privacy.

Comment: thats the problem, thats exactly what i am trying to do. But FunctionFlipper.app is inside FunctionFlipper.prefpane and it wont let me click the .prefpane because its greyed out.

Comment: maybe I do not understand- go to system preferences- security and privacy- privacy tab- select accessibility- is the FunctionFlipper showing there?

Comment: No, and when i click the plus button to add functionflipper and navigate to it in the finder it is grayed out and cant click on it to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest OS X Yosemite. You can’t select or drag `prefPane` extension file from the Finder window dialog.

When you’re prompted with the same screen, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter the path to the packaged application at:

`~/Library/PreferencePanes/FunctionFlip.prefPane/Contents/Resources/`

Check out the gif to see how it works.

[image: Move PrefPane packaged application into Security & Privacy]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did exactly as you said and it showed the FunctionFlip.app in the Resources folder after i manually entered the path, but when i clicked FunctionFlip.app and hit open it did not add it to the list, my list remains completely empty.

Comment: function flip seems to be working, but it isnt listed in the apps. So it behaves as if it is listed but is invisible in the list...

Comment: Great, if the answer addresses your problem, please choose it as answer to mark this as answered.

Comment: i guess it does, its just weird it is invisible in my privacy pane